# Asp.Net MVC não executa JQuery após chamar Action através de "url:"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Preciso chamar uma Action usando Ajax e até então tudo certo, faço o request da seguinte forma:

```
confirm: function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: urlToDelete + id,
                success: function () {
                    //window.location = urlToDelete + id; <- forma que funciona porém não considero segura, não consigo usar o Request.IsAjaxRequest() no controller, tornando-o vulnerável.
                }
            });
        },
```

ele entra na Action, executa tudo perfeitamente e retorna para a minha View. Na view tenho o seguinte trecho:

```
@if (TempData["Alerta"] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(TempData["Alerta"].ToString()))
{
    <script type="text/javascript">var msg = '@Html.Raw(TempData["Alerta"])';</script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/dialog/alertNaoExcluido.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    TempData["Alerta"] = null;
}
```

neste trecho, passo para a variável *'msg'* o valor do meu *TempData*, que seria uma mensagem de erro. Eis o problema, executando desta forma (com Ajax) a mensagem de erro não exibe na tela.

Retirando o *'url'* e descomentando o trecho '*window.location*' ele funciona tudo da mesma forma, porém executa o alerta que eu quero. Acredito que o problema é com o Ajax, que não executa um Jquery ou Javascript após o retorno de uma view que foi feita com ele.

JQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.confirm({
            icon: 'fa fa-warning text-warning',
            title: 'Atenção',
            keyboardEnabled: true,
            content: msg,
            confirmButton: 'OK',
            cancelButtonClass: 'hide',
            animation: 'top',
        });

        msg = null;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia retornar um JsonResult com sua mensagem, e tratar a mesma no success do seu javascript. Algo tipo:

Action

```
public ActionResult Delete(long id)
{

    /*Lógica da sua action*/

    //aqui retorna no data sua menssagem
    return new JsonResult() { Data = "Deletado com sucesso", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

Javascript

```
$.ajax({
url: urlToDelete + id,
success: function (data) {
    //Aqui você exibe sua mensagem, pode apendar a um modal ou topo da pagina..

    $.confirm({
        icon: 'fa fa-warning text-warning',
        title: 'Atenção',
        keyboardEnabled: true,
        content: data,
        confirmButton: 'OK',
        cancelButtonClass: 'hide',
        animation: 'top',
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27079/discussion-on-answer-by-brunno-asp-net-mvc-nao-executa-jquery-apos-chamar-action)